# Create subdirectory, set name from string C#

Tags: c#, directory

I wonder how i can create a folder and the name of the folder is a value from a string.

This

```
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath2);
    foreach (string directory in directories)
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + directory);                 
    }
```

or this

```
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath2);
    foreach (string directory in directories)
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + @"/"+directory+"/");                 
    }
```

throws a `NotSupportedException`

How can I do it?

Comment: Check out the Path.Combine method for making new directory paths correctly and easily.

Comment: you need to extract only directory name in your for loop,check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** if i understand correctly, you wanted to create the directories under the given path.

As others already stated it throws `NotSupportedException` when there is a colon `:` which is not part of the drive letter.

**From MSDN :** [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> path contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label
>   ("C:\").

if you want to create a `directory` under the given path, you need to extract only the `directory` name(without drive path) from the `directory` variable which contains overall directory path including drive path which you does not need.

**Solution:** You need to extract only the `DirectoryName` from the `directory` variable in which it contains whole directory path (which also includes drive path- which is leading to Exception)

Try This:

```
foreach (string directory in directories)
{
  Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath + @"/" + 
                        directory.Substring(directory.LastIndexOf("\\")) + "/");
```

}

Comment: I set a breakpoint and I found the reason of that exception. It was a silly mistake.

Comment: @vasilis: great :) , glad tobe help of you

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation on MSDN ( [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) a `NotSupportedException` is raised when a "*path contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label ("C:\").*" Check what is the content of your string.

Also in this regard remember:

- Any and all directories specified in path are created, unless they
  already exist or unless some part of path is invalid.
- If the directory already exists, this method does not create a new
  directory, but it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the existing
  directory.
- The path parameter specifies a directory path, not a file path.
- Trailing spaces are removed from the end of the path parameter before
  creating the directory.
- You can create a directory on a remote computer, on a share that you
  have write access to. UNC paths are supported; for example, you can
  specify the following for path: \2009\Archives\December in Visual
  Basic, and \\2009\Archives\December in C#.
- Creating a directory with only the colon character (:) is not
  supported, and will cause a NotSupportedException to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documents the possible exceptions along with the error conditions.

> **NotSupportedException**
>
> path contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label ("C:\").

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says

NotSupportedException: path contains a colon character (:) that is not part of a drive label ("C:\").

Take a look [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h4z99zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)